# How to get Reuseable ViewComponent in class library (Dotnet core 3.0)

Tags: c#, .net-core, razorengine, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

In Dotnet Core 2.1 in am using below code to get the viewComponent from class library.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    var assembly = typeof(ViewComponentLibrary.ViewComponents.SimpleViewComponent).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

    //Create an EmbeddedFileProvider for that assembly
    var embeddedFileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(
        assembly,
        "ViewComponentLibrary"
    );

    //Add the file provider to the Razor view engine
    services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
    {                
        options.FileProviders.Add(embeddedFileProvider);
    });
}
```

But in Dotnet Core 3.0 , i could not found the File Provider in RazorViewEngineOptions. Could some one advise how to get the viewComponent or .cshtml from class library ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14374

AddRazorRuntimeCompilation() and change the library class to Razor class library